# How can I use GitLab under a relative URL on docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, docker-compose

I'm using gitlab-ce on docker.
These are my system specifications.

- A container of GitLab is gitlab/gitlab-ce.
- The web frontend is using external NGINX.
- GitLab is mounted under /git.

I read the the [gitlab documentation for configuring of a relative url](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/relative_url.html), but it does not work as expected.
My expected behavior is that I access `http:localhost/git/` as a root of GitLab.
But NGINX or GiLab redirects `/user/_login` instead of `/git/user/_login`.

All my configurations can be found in the following git project: https://github.com/elda27/test-gitlab

And this is my Dockerfile constructing GitLab.
All configurations store an above url.

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-ce

WORKDIR /var/opt/gitlab/
RUN mkdir -p ./gitlab-rails/etc/ && chown git:git ./gitlab-rails/etc/
RUN mkdir -p ./gitlab-shell && chown git:git ./gitlab-shell

ADD --chown=root:root gitlab.rb /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
ADD --chown=root:root relative_url.rb /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/relative_url.rb
ADD --chown=root:root puma.rb /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/puma.yml
ADD --chown=root:git gitlab.yml /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml
ADD --chown=root:git config.yml /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/config.yml

WORKDIR /
```

Please advise configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problems reference with the following document: ​
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html

I need to set `external_url` and disable internal NGINX in the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.

```ruby
# See: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server
external_url "http://localhost/git"

# NGINX config
nginx['enable'] = false
web_server['external_users'] = ['nginx']
web_server['username'] = 'nginx'
# web_server['group'] = 101

# rails config
gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = ['172.17.0.0/16']

# HTTPS config
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
mattermost_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false

letsencrypt['enable'] = false
```

And configuration of external NGINX is following.

```
upstream gitlab {
  # Unix socket for Gitlabs
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_tokens off; # Disable the nginx server version

  location ^~ /git/ {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    # rewrite ^/git/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    # proxy_pass http://gitlab:8080;
    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
  location / {
    root /opt/app;
    index index.html index.html;
  }
}
```

I mistake to understand between source installation and Omnibus GitLab.
There configurations are separate documented, but I'm not known it.
All configuration is written in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` on the Omnibus GitLab in the docker container.